# bash: ./flash_tool: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: permissions, phone, tools

I try to run SP Flash Tool under Ubuntu MATE but after I `chmod +x` the executable file, I get this error:

```
bash: ./flash_tool: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
bash: ./flash_tool.sh: Permission denied
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The `Exec format error` means you are using the wrong file for your computer.  Most likely you were trying to use the 64 bit version on a 32 bit Ubuntu.  You need to download the right one.

Type `arch` in a terminal to be sure which you should use.

If you get something like `i386` as I suspect, download the "Linux 32 Bit version" under the heading "Direct links for SP Flash Tool Download" from http://spflashtool.com/

*Currently, the supposed 32-bit version hosted there is in fact also 64-bit, and so no usable version is available for 32-bit Ubuntu.  You might be able to find a 32-bit one elsewhere, but be careful.  You cannot be certain any of these downloads (including the above link) are virus-free.*

If you get `x86_64` choose "Download SPFlashTool for Linux - 64 Bit Tool"

Comment: For arch command i get the following response: i686

Comment: Download the 32 bit version.

Comment: ok, but is the same, bash: ./flash_tool.sh: Permission denied. btw i open the files folder as a administrator and in terminal i executed the flash_tool as superuser after i chmod +x the exec file!

Comment: chmod +x flash_tool.sh
 ./flash_tool.sh
./flash_tool.sh: line 13: /.../SP_Flash_Tool_Linux_v5.1520.00.100/./flash_tool: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: type `file flash_tool` while in the same directory as `flash_tool.sh`.  Does it say it is `ELF 64-bit`?

Comment: It will.  I've just checked it myself, and their 32-bit download in fact isn't.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Download for 32bit Linux on http://spflashtool.com/ is **not** 32bit, it is the 64bit Version.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens You might get this error is you execute the 64 bit version on a 32bit OS.

Answer (score -1):

Run it as non root user. I'm on Kali Linux with root user by default and I was able to run the flash_tool using a non root user , through gksu:

<< gksu -u my_non_root_user ./flash_tool.sh >>

On Ubuntu it should work without sudo I suppose.

That works for me. I hope it may help!

Comment: That won't help. It's the wrong executable type for the system in question and unrelated to super-user privileges. See the other answers. -1